# Can a disabled WPF scrollviewer be scrollable?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

The scenario is a control that is disabled because users should not make changes. Inside this control is a [`ScrollViewer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (among other controls) and when the parent is disabled it cannot be scrolled. Ideally the user should be able to scroll this scrollviewer so they can see its contents (the contents should remain disabled).

Just wondering if there was some simple xaml that could let a disabled scrollview be scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Override the Metadata in the Application_Startup event of the application, like so:

```
ScrollViewer.IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ScrollViewer), new UIPropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback(ScrollViewer_IsEnabledPropertyChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(ScrollViewerForceEnabled)));
```

Handle the CoerceValueCallback to always return true, like so:

```
private static void ScrollViewer_IsEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) { }
private static object ScrollViewerForceEnabled(DependencyObject source, object value)
{
    return true;
}
```